# Bluetooth client-server communication [java]

Tags: java, eclipse, bluetooth

I tried some blue-tooth chat program that involves

```
import javax.bluetooth.*
```

and my eclipse shows that as error saying **import javax.... cannot be resolved**

I am using Linux.. Will the Java bluetooth specific program is portable to other OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Will the Java bluetooth specific program is portable to other OS.
```

**YES**

- make sure you have already imported jars to eclipse build path right click in your project folder --> properties -->

[image]

**or try**

Right click on project - >BuildPath - >Configure BuildPath - >Libraries tab - >

Double click on JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY - >Then select alternate JRE